# What does `endpoint` exactly mean in OAuth?

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth, google-plus

I saw the word "`endpoint`" many times in OAuth documents.. However, I still don't know what does this word really mean.. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 2):

[The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

> The authorization process utilizes two authorization server endpoints
> (HTTP resources):
>
> - Authorization endpoint - used by the client to obtain
>   authorization from the resource owner via user-agent redirection.
> - Token endpoint - used by the client to exchange an
>   authorization
>   grant for an access token, typically with client authentication.

Its basically the HTTP web address of the authentication server.  It could probably be server addresses depending upon how its worked. The first is for requesting access of the user the second could be for granting access to the application. this probably depends upon how the Authentication server is set up.

OAuth endpoints are the URLs you use to make OAuth authentication requests to Server. You need to use the correct OAuth endpoint when issuing authentication requests in your application. The primary OAuth endpoints depend upon the system you are trying to access.

Example Google has two end points:

Request access of user:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2

Exchange tokens

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token